# Jumpy and Incomplete XAML Window Drag with C# TouchMove

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a small undecorated xaml window for a touch screen. The user must be able to move the window using touch and drag. Currently on touch and drag, the window moves in the direction of the drag, but only part way; and there appears to be two windows rather than one, making the touch and drag appear jumpy.

This behavior manifests on the development system (Surface Pro 3 using Visual Studio Professional 2015) as well as on the production system (Windows 7, no keyboard or mouse).

I based this C# on Microsoft's [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727735.aspx).

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace XAMLApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private TouchDevice windowTouchDevice;
        private Point lastPoint;

        private void Circle_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do stuff.
        }

        private void Window_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            e.TouchDevice.Capture(this);

            if (windowTouchDevice == null)
            {
                windowTouchDevice = e.TouchDevice;
                lastPoint = windowTouchDevice.GetTouchPoint(null).Position;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void Window_TouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.TouchDevice == windowTouchDevice)
            {
                var currentTouchPoint = windowTouchDevice.GetTouchPoint(null);

                var deltaX = currentTouchPoint.Position.X - lastPoint.X;
                var deltaY = currentTouchPoint.Position.Y - lastPoint.Y;

                Top += deltaY;
                Left += deltaX;

                lastPoint = currentTouchPoint.Position;

                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Window_TouchLeave(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.TouchDevice == windowTouchDevice)
                windowTouchDevice = null;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's some xaml for the window.

```
<Window x:Name="AppWindow" x:Class="XAMLApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="XAML Application"
        Height="25" Width="25"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        ShowInTaskbar="False" ToolTip="XAML Application" Topmost="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"
        MaxHeight="25" MaxWidth="25" MinHeight="25" MinWidth="25"
        Left="0" Top="0" Background="Transparent"
        TouchDown="Window_TouchDown"
        TouchMove="Window_TouchMove"
        TouchLeave="Window_TouchLeave">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="Circle" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Height="24" Margin="0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="24" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                 TouchUp="Circle_TouchUp" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've tried replacing the `Grid` with a `Canvas`. That made no difference. I also tried using Manipulation as [demonstrated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090(v=vs.110).aspx) by Microsoft. When trying to drag the window, I was told that the transformation was invalid for the window.

How can I make the touch and drag behave the same as `DragMove()` using a left-mouse-click-and-drag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TouchPoint` retrieved through the `TouchDevice.GetTouchPoint` method and the window's `Top` and `Left` attributes do not share the same coordinate system. All you need to do is convert the X and Y values retrieved to screen coordinates:

```
private void Window_TouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TouchDevice == windowTouchDevice)
    {
        var currentTouchPoint = windowTouchDevice.GetTouchPoint(null);

        var locationOnScreen = this.PointToScreen(new Point(currentTouchPoint.Position.X, currentTouchPoint.Position.Y));

        var deltaX = locationOnScreen.X - lastPoint.X;
        var deltaY = locationOnScreen.Y - lastPoint.Y;

        Top += deltaY;
        Left += deltaX;

        lastPoint = locationOnScreen;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Of course, the thing about different coordinate systems applies to the whole project, so the `Window_TouchDown` event handler method needs to be adapted in a similar way:

```
private void Window_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    e.TouchDevice.Capture(this);

    if (windowTouchDevice == null)
    {
        windowTouchDevice = e.TouchDevice;
        var currentTouchPoint = windowTouchDevice.GetTouchPoint(null);
        var locationOnScreen = this.PointToScreen(new Point(currentTouchPoint.Position.X, currentTouchPoint.Position.Y));
        lastPoint = locationOnScreen;
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Ah, a few seconds too late... But if you're still interested, my answer might explain why your original solution did'nt work.

Comment: I'll go ahead and award the bounty to you because I appreciate you clarifying the issue. The code you provided, however, actually makes the Window disappear from the screen, so it could use an edit. I'll leave my answer marked as the answer, since it's how I resolved my issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're right, there's a little thing missing from the solution. I've edited the answer to give the whole picture!

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Top += deltaY;
Left += deltaX;
```

I just needed

```
Top += currentTouchPoint.Position.Y;
Left += currentTouchPoint.Position.X;
```

Ugh.